# How to solve "Invalid Taxonomy", displays Array array on WordPress page?

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, custom-taxonomy

When I `var_dump($term_list)`;

```
$term_list = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'functiongroups', array("fields" => "names")); 

foreach ($term_list as $term) { $i++;
         echo '.$term.';
         echo ($i > 0 && !($i % 2 == 0)) ? ', ' : '';
};
```

I'm getting this:

```
WP_Error Object ([errors] => Array ([invalid_taxonomy] => Array ([0]
=> Invalid Taxonomy)) [error_data] => Array ())
```

, and displays Array array on WordPress page and not the expected taxonomy.

Comment: `$myVar` doesn't mean anything without context...Where did that variable come from?

Comment: @rnevius I've added it to the question. thanks for responding! Bytheway your contact form plugin works great :D

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The name of the taxonomy didn't exist (i.e. a taxonomy created using a plugin like advanced-custom-fields or any other plugin using taxonomies) or was misspelled when using `wp_get_post_terms();`.  (In my case '**functiongroups**' didn't exist);

Note that the taxonomy could be added programmatically as well, not only by using a plugin:

```
function functiongroups_init() {
    // create a new taxonomy
    register_taxonomy(
        'functiongroups',
        'post',
        array(
            'label' => __( 'Functiongroups' ),
            ...
        )
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'functiongroups_init' );
```